My User Login Form is returning the error “django.db.utils.IntegrityError”
I am building a django project and I keep getting this error:
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "id" of relation "validation" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, 7, 839510, 0, 2024-10-29 19:51:34.057435+00, f, null).

I think it has something to do with my database; I use pgadmin
views.py:
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render  
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate  
from django.core.mail import send_mail  
from django.utils import timezone  
from .forms import UserRegistrationForm, UserLoginForm, VerificationForm  
from .models import Validation  

# User Registration View  
def register_view(request):  
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)  
        if form.is_valid():  
            user = form.save()  
            login(request, user)  
            token = random.randint(100000, 999999)  
            Validation.objects.create(user=user, token=token,  
                                      expired=timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(hours=1))  
            send_mail(  
                'Your Verification Code',  
                f'Use this code to verify your account: {token}',  
                settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,  
                [user.email],  
            )  
            return redirect('verification')  
    else:  
        form = UserRegistrationForm()  
    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form': form})  

# Verification View  
def verify_view(request):  
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        form = VerificationForm(request.POST)  
        if form.is_valid():  
            token = form.cleaned_data['token']  
            try:  
                validation = Validation.objects.get(user=request.user)  
                if validation.token == int(token) and validation.expired >= timezone.now():  
                    validation.validation_status = True  
                    validation.save()  
                    return redirect('profile')  
                else:  
                    # Handle case where verification fails  
            except Validation.DoesNotExist:  
                pass  
    else:  
        form = VerificationForm()  
    return render(request, 'registration/verify_email.html', {'form': form})models.py

# Create your models here.

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    company_name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='logos/', null=True, blank=True)
    validation = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    
class Validation(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # Links to User model
    token = models.BigIntegerField()
    tries = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    expired = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)  # Set default to current time
    validation_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    validation_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.expired = timezone.now() + timedelta(minutes=10)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def check_expiry_and_increment_tries(self):
        if timezone.now() > self.expired:
            self.tries += 1
            self.expired = timezone.now() + timedelta(minutes=10)  # Reset expiry time
            self.save()

    def generate_verification_code(self):
        self.token = uuid.uuid4().int >> 64  # Generate a large integer token
        self.expired = timezone.now() + timedelta(minutes=10)
        self.save()

    def is_verification_code_valid(self):
        return timezone.now() <= self.expired

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'validation'

class Link(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.TextField()
    url = models.TextField()
    logo = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    clicks = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        is_new = not self.pk
        old_logo = None

        if self.pk:
            old_logo = Link.objects.filter(pk=self.pk).first().logo

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        # Handle logo file saving and old file deletion
        if self.logo and is_new:
            file_extension = os.path.splitext(self.logo)[1]
            new_filename = f"{self.user.username}_{self.id}_{slugify(self.title)}{file_extension}"
            user_folder = os.path.join('logos/', self.user.username)
            new_path = os.path.join(user_folder, new_filename)

            if not os.path.exists(user_folder):
                os.makedirs(user_folder)

            # Save new logo path to the database
            self.logo = new_path
            super().save(update_fields=['logo'])

        # Delete old logo if replaced
        if old_logo and old_logo != self.logo:
            try:
                old_file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, old_logo)
                if os.path.exists(old_file_path):
                    os.remove(old_file_path)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error deleting old file: {e}")

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'links'

forms.py:
from django import forms  
from django.contrib.auth.models import User  
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm  
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError  
from .models import Validation   

# User Login Form  
class UserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):  
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=254, required=True)  
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", strip=False, widget=forms.PasswordInput)  

    class Meta:  
        model = User  
        fields = ['username', 'password']  

# Verification Form  
class VerificationForm(forms.Form):  
    token = forms.CharField(max_length=6, required=True, label="Verification Code")  

    def clean_token(self):  
        token = self.cleaned_data['token']  
        if not token.isdigit() or len(token) != 6:  
            raise ValidationError("Invalid verification code format.")  
        return token  

# User Registration Form  
class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):  
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True)  
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True)  
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)  

    class Meta:  
        model = User  
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']  

    def clean_email(self):  
        email = self.cleaned_data['email'].lower()  
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():  
            raise ValidationError("A user with that email already exists.")  
        return email

validation table
links

We need to know which lines of the code you have posted give rise to the exception. The error traceback will contain this information.

You don't need to use this line in your Validation and Link models:
id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
remove this line !

If you want to keep the line:
id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)

You should add auto_created = True :
id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created = True)

Else it is null as you get in your error message.
But you needn't really this line. Django do it by itself.
